# Finding specific solution for second order nonhomogeneous recurrence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

$\ x(n+2)−1/2x(n+1)+1/8x(n)=cos(nπ/2)$

Guess a solution -$\ Acos(nπ/2)+Bsin(nπ/2)$ where A and B are constants

There were a question about this exact problem yersterday - [Need help finding specific solution for second order nonhomogenous recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000510/need-help-finding-specific-solution-for-second-order-nonhomogenous-recurrence-re)

But I did not understand the answer given, could someone explain what to do step-by-step after I have gotten to:

$\ x(n+2)−1/2x(n+1)+1/8x(n) = \Bigl(A\cos\frac{(n+2)\pi}2+B\sin\frac{(n+2)\pi}2\Bigr)
  -\frac12\Bigl(A\cos\frac{(n+1)\pi}2+B\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}2\Bigr)
  +\frac18\Bigl(A\cos\frac{n\pi}2+B\sin\frac{n\pi}2\Bigr)\ $

I am stuck...

Comment: The next step is to simplify the cosine terms, see [my answer to the question you referred to](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000510/need-help-finding-specific-solution-for-second-order-nonhomogenous-recurrence-re/1000536#1000536).  Then do something similar for the sine terms.

Comment: You linked to the same question I did in the post, I get the simplification part, but I did not understand how to find the values of A and B afterwards. This - "Then equate coefficients of LHS and RHS." does not tell me much

Comment: "Equate coefficients" means that all the coefficients of $\cos(n\pi/2)$ on the LHS must add up to the coefficient of $\cos(n\pi/2)$ on the RHS, which is $1$.  Similarly, all the $\sin(n\pi/2)$ coefficients must add up to $0$.  This gives you two equations in two unknowns and you can solve them to find $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering each term and simplifying, we have $$ A\cos\frac{(n+2)\pi}2+B\sin\frac{(n+2)\pi}2=-A \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-B \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)$$ $$ A\cos\frac{(n+1)\pi}2+B\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}2=B \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-A \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)$$ $$ A\cos\frac{n\pi}2+B\sin\frac{n\pi}2=A \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+B \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)$$ Now combine the terms with the appropriate coefficients and, after simplifications, the lhs write $$\frac{1}{8} \left((4 A-7 B) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-(7 A+4 B) \cos
   \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)\right)$$ Compare with the rhs, identify and conclude.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I feel bad for asking, but I dont think I can follow how to do next steps, I missed about 2 weeks worth of lectures so I am kind of clueless, and book gives only very simplistic examples...

Comment: If you compare lhs to rhs, I suppose that $4A-7B=0$ since there is no $\sin(.)$ and that $-(7A+4B)=8$. Is that clear ? If not, just post.